# bmp Image Resizing and Fit to page in c#

Tags: c#

I have Image of width 1171 and height 1181. I need that image into print page using printDocument...So Final image size would be width 596 and height 892. So it covers all area of page without any space.
My problem is I am able to resize it but it does not cover the whole space of page...And with different solution it covers the whole page area but image cutted down.

So what I have to do for solving this issue?

My code as per below...

```
private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnPrint.Enabled = false;
            try
            {

                printDocument1.Print();
                this.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Printing failed :" + err.Message);
                btnPrint.Enabled = true;
            }

        }

        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {

            Image img = ((PictureBox)pictureBox1).Image;
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)img;
            bmp.Save("abcc");
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bmp, new Size(892, 596));
                // Bitmap b = ResizeBitmap(bmp, 892, 596);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
                e.Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                e.Graphics.Transform.Scale(0, 0);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap,new Rectangle(0,0,892,596),new Rectangle(0,0,bmp.Width,bmp.Height),GraphicsUnit.Pixel);





        }
```

Comment: Do you have some issue with the code? Or just showing solution for other to review?

Comment: hi...This code is not working for me as it did not resized image to 892 * 596 from 1280 * 1150.

Comment: Consider debugging and reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839358/resize-bitmap-image . If it does not help edit your sample so it only includes code to reproduce the issue and add problem details to the post.