# Reduce Bitmap resolution and speed up saving

Tags: c#, .net

Every certain time I get a screenshot of an area or the entire screen (of the game) in Bitmap [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkx9p.jpg). Then I saved it via Bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp). After looking at other formats, Bmp turned out to be the fastest, but it's still not enough.

[Bmp efficiency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A61LM.png) vs [Jpeg efficiency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtO4K.png)

My code at the moment:

```
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
frame.Bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
var bytes = ms.ToArray();
```

I tried to save to Jpeg degrading the quality, but the efficiency is also small:

```
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
//frame.Bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
SaveBitmapWithQuality(frame.Bitmap, 10, ms);
var bytes = ms.ToArray();

static void SaveBitmapWithQuality(Bitmap bitmap, int quality, MemoryStream outputStream)
{
    if (quality is < 0 or > 100)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(quality), "quality must be in [0..100].");
    }

    ImageCodecInfo bmpEncoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().Where(codec => codec.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid).Single();
    var qualityEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
    var encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
    encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(qualityEncoder, quality);
    bitmap.Save(outputStream, bmpEncoder, encoderParams);
}
```

How can I lower the quality so that the picture weighs less and speed up saving?

Comment: You just can't get the data fast enough, overhead imposed by Aero.  Getting ahead requires staying on the GPU, both to access the data and to encode it.  Google "c# screen recorder" for hits.

Comment: Hans' comment aside, google `c# reduce bitmap size` for how to reduce the size. Here's an [example question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839358/resize-bitmap-image) from my quick search. Saving in jpeg format is never going to be super fast as that process requires quite a bit of analysis/processing.